# using plugin metrics-reporter-prometheus to monitor Gerrit internals with Prometheus

Tags: gerrit, monitor, prometheus

I want to monitor [Gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/) daemon with [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/).

How to configure Gerrit's plugin [metrics-reporter-prometheus](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/metrics-reporter-prometheus) and Prometheus for white-box monitoring ?

Disclaimer: This exporter mostly exposes Gerrit daemon internal metrics, generated from [Dropwizard metric](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics). **Project count, pending reviews ... are not reported**

Note 2: I am not interested in using the generic exporters (JMX exporter, Javamelody...)

This exporters typical metrics looks like:

```
# HELP caches_disk_cached_git_tags Generated from Dropwizard metric import (metric=caches/disk_cached/git_tags, type=com.google.gerrit.metrics.dropwizard.BucketedCallback$ValueGauge)
# TYPE caches_disk_cached_git_tags gauge
caches_disk_cached_git_tags 0.0
# HELP http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_project_ListProjects Generated from Dropwizard metric import (metric=http/server/rest_api/response_bytes/project.ListProjects, type=com.codahale.metrics.Histogram)
# TYPE http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_project_ListProjects summary
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_project_ListProjects{quantile="0.5",} 216.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_project_ListProjects{quantile="0.75",} 216.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_project_ListProjects{quantile="0.95",} 216.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_project_ListProjects{quantile="0.98",} 216.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_project_ListProjects{quantile="0.99",} 216.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_project_ListProjects{quantile="0.999",} 216.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_project_ListProjects_count 3.0
# HELP http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_query_change_QueryChanges Generated from Dropwizard metric import (metric=http/server/rest_api/response_bytes/query.change.QueryChanges, type=com.codahale.metrics.Histogram)
# TYPE http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_query_change_QueryChanges summary
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_query_change_QueryChanges{quantile="0.5",} 16.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_query_change_QueryChanges{quantile="0.75",} 16.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_query_change_QueryChanges{quantile="0.95",} 16.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_query_change_QueryChanges{quantile="0.98",} 16.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_query_change_QueryChanges{quantile="0.99",} 16.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_query_change_QueryChanges{quantile="0.999",} 16.0
http_server_rest_api_response_bytes_query_change_QueryChanges_count 17.0
[..]
[..]
```

and some usual like

```
# HELP proc_jvm_memory_heap_committed Generated from Dropwizard metric import (metric=proc/jvm/memory/heap_committed, type=com.google.gerrit.metrics.dropwizard.CallbackMetricImpl0$1)
# TYPE proc_jvm_memory_heap_committed gauge
proc_jvm_memory_heap_committed 5.77241088E8
# HELP proc_birth_timestamp Generated from Dropwizard metric import (metric=proc/birth_timestamp, type=com.google.gerrit.metrics.dropwizard.CallbackMetricImpl0$1)
# TYPE proc_birth_timestamp gauge
proc_birth_timestamp 1.525600508281E15
# HELP proc_cpu_usage Generated from Dropwizard metric import (metric=proc/cpu/usage, type=com.google.gerrit.metrics.dropwizard.CallbackMetricImpl0$1)
# TYPE proc_cpu_usage gauge
proc_cpu_usage 93.24
# HELP proc_num_open_fds Generated from Dropwizard metric import (metric=proc/num_open_fds, type=com.google.gerrit.metrics.dropwizard.CallbackMetricImpl0$1)
# TYPE proc_num_open_fds gauge
```

Answer (score 6):

Answering myself...

How it works: Prometheus will scrape

## Gerrit configuration

Assumptions:

- Gerrit is installed in the directory `~/gerrit`
- Gerrit version is >= 2.14 (the examples based on 2.14)
- Gerrit SSH is configured with an SSH key ([doc](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/install-quick.html)), this command works  `ssh -p 29418 admin@gerrit.example.com gerrit version`

**Install the Plugin**

Install the Gerrit exporter plugin. The easier is to download the JAR from gerritforge. Browse https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-stable-2.14/job/pluin-metrics-reporter-prometheus-bazel-stable-2.14/ and download `metrics-reporter-prometheus.jar`, or execute the Unix commands:

```
cd ~/gerrit/plugins/
wget -O metrics-reporter-prometheus.jar 'https://gerrit-ci.gerritforge.com/view/Plugins-stable-2.14/job/plugin-metrics-reporter-prometheus-bazel-stable-2.14/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/bazel-genfiles/plugins/metrics-reporter-prometheus/metrics-reporter-prometheus.jar'
```

Then restart Gerrit

Connect as an admin in the Gerrit web interface, got to Plugins>Installed to verify that metrics-reporter-prometheus is listed and enabled, or run:

```
ssh -p 29418 admin@gerrit.example.com gerrit plugin ls
```

**Authorize the account and group**

Next you need to create a group and an account in Gerrit, then grant the capability `View Metrics`.

This procedure should be adapted to how you manage your user account in Gerrit (LDAP...). For local account (managed by SSH):

```
ssh -p 29418 admin@gerrit.example.com 'gerrit create-group "Prometheus Metrics" '

ssh -p 29418 admin@gerrit.example.com 'gerrit create-account prometheus  --full-name "Prometheus Monitoring" --email prometheus@gerrit.example.com '

ssh -p 29418 admin@gerrit.example.com 'gerrit set-members "Prometheus Metrics" --add "prometheus" '

ssh -p 29418 admin@gerrit.example.com 'gerrit set-account prometheus --http-password ChangeThisInsecurePassword '
```

**Grant 'Prometheus Metrics' permissions in Gerrit**

- Log in to Gerrit web interface with an account with admin privileges, go to Projects>List>All-Projects
- Click on the tab 'Access'
- Click on the button [EDIT]
- In the block `Global Capabilities`, click on `Add Permission` (that's typically the 4th drop down menu)

  - Select the permission `View Metrics` in the drop-down list
  - Select the group "Prometheus Metrics" we created above.
  - Click on the button [Add]
  - Go to the bottom of the page and **click on the [Save Changes] button**

**Test !**

Test authentication and authorization, there are two options:
    * Login the web interface with the create account (which should succeed!), then change the URL path (`http://gerrit.example.com:8080/a/plugins/metrics-reporter-prometheus/metrics`), you should get Prometheus metrics!
    * or Use `wget` (or `curl` or whatever):

```
wget -O - --user prometheus --password ChangeThisInsecurePassword  http://gerrit.example.com:8080/a/plugins/metrics-reporter-prometheus/metrics
```

**IMPORTANT You may have to prefix Gerrit URL with `/a/`** to force HTTP authentication ([read the doc](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#authentication))

If you get the error `ERROR 403: Forbidden access.`, double check the procedure above (user exist? group exist ? permissions granted ?)!

## Prometheus configuration

Edit the file `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`, add a job:

```yaml
  - job_name: gerrit
    metrics_path: '/a/plugins/metrics-reporter-prometheus/metrics'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['slxhmhs1:8080']
    basic_auth:
      username: prometheus
      password: ChangeThisInsecurePassword
```

Check promethsu configuration file:

```
promtool  check-config /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

Let prometheus reload it's configuration, using one of:

```
systemctl reload prometheus
killall -HUP prometheus
docker exec -ti graphite-exporter killall -HUP prometheus
```

**Test:**

Visit Prometheus' status page (http://prom.example.com:9090/targets#job-gerrit ), then check the job/target status.

**Use**

Go to prometheus Expression browser (http://prom.example.com:9090 ), then type :

```
{job="gerrit"}
```

And enjoy in Grafana :-)